# Why does an electric field oppose the flow of positive ion?

Tags: capacitance, biophysics

[image]

I'm solving a very interesting problem.

Suppose a cell is divided into inside and outside. Inside we have positive ions and outside we also have positive ions in different concentration.

Suppose a concentration difference of potassium K+ causes it to flow outwards from the inside (while the other ions are fixed), then there would be a deficiency of positive ions on the inside, thereby creating a electric field across the cell membrane (just like a capacitor).

Can someone explain to me, why after there has been an electric field set up between the outside and the inside, no more positive K+ ions may flow from inside to the outside?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your physics background is. The phenomenon you describe comes from the equation of continuity. This can be concisely mathematically expressed as
$$ \oint  \left( {\bf J}  + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial {\bf E}}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d{\bf S} = 0 $$

In this equation ${\bf J}$ is an electrical current density (current per unit area) and $\partial {\bf E}/\partial t$ is the rate of change of electric field ($\epsilon_0$ is just a physical constant to get the units right). The equation says that the sum of these two things integrated over a closed surface must equal zero. That is, if you move charge into or out of a volume then the electric field will change and it will change in a direction to oppose the flow of charge. i.e. if you keep putting positive charges into a volume, then an electric field will build up that opposes the flow of positive charge into the volume.

The second part of the answer (and perhaps the main thing you are asking) is how the electric field that is set up opposes the flow of charge? This is a straightforward consequence of the component of the Lorentz force exerted by electromagnetic fields on charged particles. In this case, considering only electric fields, the force is given by ${\bf F} = q{\bf E}$, where the quantities are vectors and the charge $q$ in the case you are  discussing is positive.

So on the diagram you show, after positive ions have been transported from inside to outside, an electric field builds up (due to the continuity equation), and this electric field is in the direction from outside to inside. The force this exerts on a positive ion is also in the direction from outside-to-inside. Eventually as more positive charges flow out of the cell, this force will become strong enough to stop the flow of charge and presumably an equilibrium will be reached where the electric field is strong enough to overcome the concentration difference.

Comment: Is electric field is force exerted on positive ion? Can you provide a link to when you said "the force this exerts on positive ion is also in the direction from outside to inside"?

Comment: I'm not sure I can provide a reference for the Lorentz force (maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force ). For a positive charge, the Lorentz force due to the electric field is in the same direction as the electric field.

Comment: So Since F = qE, sign(q) = +1 , therefore the force is the same direction as the electric field. But then wouldn't negative ions be attracted to the outside thereby bring this membrane back into equilibrium?

Comment: Yes. Any negative ions would feel a force in the opposite direction.